# Static methods, non static members - Data Access Layer/Business Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0, web-applications, architecture

OK, i am creating a web application. I am using MVC3. I have ViewModel for every view and also I have Data Model that supports viewModel and does the actuall CRUD operation in my sql table, while my viewModel validates and alters data as necessary.

Here is a question. The way I have been coding is

```
 public class MyClassViewModel
 {
     public string member1{get;set;}
     public int member2{get;set;}

      public static GetAllMembers(MyClassViewModel obj, out string strErrMsg)
      {
          // code goes here, read operation
      }

      public static UpdateMyClass(MyClassViewModel obj, out string strErrMsg)
      {
           // code goes here, write operation.
      }
 }
```

Both My ViewModel and DataModels have been coded this way, My Controller on  HttpPost just do something like this..

```
 MyClassViewModel.UpdateMember(obj,out strErrMsg)
```

Since its mvc on every post it creates on a strongly typed view, a new object of my ViewModel, hence non static members are different and are not shared between sessions.

I am using Linq and therefore on each static method of my DataModel i use

```
  var db = new MyApplicationDataContext()
```

to get my linq classes and work on them. This solves my open/close reader problems.

My question is, are there any issues regarding concurrency with this design? I know I might have problems in changing my data layer if it is not designed via interface, but I highly doubt that is necessary based on my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially using the factory design pattern.  That's OK pattern to use for this; each static method has its own context, and that's OK too.  You always have to worry about concurrency; however, the LINQ to SQL architecture has concurrency detection built in and throws a ChangeConflictException when a concurrent change has been made in reaction to this.

I would also highly recommend that you are disposing your contexts properly at the end of each static method call, because you could leave open connections to the database which can cause performance problems.

Also, another problem you may run into is interlinking data; you cannot link two objects together by reference that were created from different contexts.  And in LINQ to SQL, there is no way to explicitly detach an object...

Comment: Yes i am aware that I have to dispose the datacontext. I also do not have a problem interlinking data because merging of more than one entities is done in viewModel which has nothing to do with linq, it just deals with datamodels.. combining different datamodels is easy.

Comment: I was referring to combining data models in a more complex update scenario; not overly difficult to deal with, but does require some concern...